# Any tutorials on setting up a templating framework on GAE (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, velocity, freemarker, stringtemplate

I'm trying to format our emails by using HTML-formatted templates on Google App Engine (using Java), but for the life of me I cannot find a decent tutorial for how to set this up.

I've tried looking at [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/), but I cannot find any examples where a stand-alone template is loaded from a servlet's context and used as a formatter.

Can anyone help?  I'm open to any suggestions, such as Velocity or FreeMarker, so long as they run on GAE.

Thanks

Comment: Freemarker depends on AWT for some bizarre reason, it won't work with GAE, it is not as good a choice as StringTemplate anyway.

Comment: FreeMarker has an official GAE-version released together with the Java version for a good while. (BTW that AWT dependency is on a generic tree API, nothing GUI-related...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out how to do it.

The documentation for StringTemplate can be very confusing.  The latest version (version 4) has different classes than previous versions (`ST` instead of `StringTemplate`, `STGroup` instead of `StringTemplateGroup`, etc)

It also has an external dependency on 'antlr'.  [Per these instructions](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Using+StringTemplate+with+Java#UsingStringTemplatewithJava-install) (link contains links to jars needed), put the 'antlr' and 'SimpleTemplate' jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory on the server.

Version 2 introduced template 'groups', which as far as I can tell, are required for loading a template from a file on a web server.

So to get it working, I had to define a template group file, with the following content, named `emailTemplate.stg`

```
html_format(keyToReplace1, keyToReplace2) ::= <<
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    This is $keyToReplace1$
    <br/>
    This is $keyToReplace2$
  </div>
</body>
</html>
>>
```

I then had to ensure this file was accessible by my code via a relative URL.  This is easily testable by going to the URL in the browser, such as at: localhost:8888/templates/emailTemplate.stg

Then, to use this template, I used the following code:

```
STGroup g = new STGroupFile("templates/emailTemplate.stg", '$', '$');
ST emailTemplate = g.getInstanceOf("html_format");
emailTemplate.add("keyToReplace1", "value for the first key");
emailTemplate.add("keyToReplace2", "value for the second key");
String result = emailTemplate.render();
```

Comment: Only the Java version seems to be affected by the name changes. The C# port keeps the "proper" names.

Answer (score 0):

You can load templates from the class path just like any other input stream to use in StringTemplate.

```
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.*;

StringTemplate hello = new StringTemplate("Hello, $name$", DefaultTemplateLexer.class);
hello.setAttribute("name", "World");
System.out.println(hello.toString());
```

you can look at the JavaDoc to see how to load a file/resource using an input stream, using [`Class.getResourceAsString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), the file needs to be on the `classpath` usually in the `default package` of your .war ( ie in the root of `/lib` ) with the .class files.

Read the resource into a `String` and substitute the first paramater with the contents, or use one of the `Stream` constructors of `StringTemplate`.

It is really simple.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this... do you know of any tutorials where I can see how this is done?  I don't know how to use StringTemplate at all.

Comment: I'm really interested in figuring out how to load a template from a context path in a web container.  I still can't find any examples that show how to do this.