# How do I use StringTemplate files in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, stringtemplate

I'm trying to use StringTemplate in Google App Engine to load a template from a file, but I cannot figure out where to put my template files.

The documentation says that StringTemplate will "Look for templates in CLASSPATH as resources" but I'm not sure what that means in terms of a GAE deployment.

For example, suppose I put my templates in a directory called "templates", and put code like this in my servlet:

```
StringTemplateGroup group = new StringTemplateGroup("mygroup", "templates");
StringTemplate st = group.getInstanceOf("homepage");
```

Then where do I put the "templates" directory?

Comment: Note this example works when I run locally in debug mode if I replace "templates" with the absolute path of the templates directory. Of course, this wont work if it is deployed to Google App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it works to put the "templates" directory in your "war" directory.

This works locally and deployed to GAE (for me, anyway).

Comment: Could you accept your own answer then? Would be useful for other users that stumbled upon the same problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to make them "static" files as far as GAE is concerned.  Rather, it seems like they need to remain "resource files" and be deployed to the same server as your app.  According to the documentation, this is the default behavior of the war directory: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?csw=1#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files

Comment: JR Lawhome-- I do believe you are correct (I am not using 'static' at all in prod), so I have amended the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ST?  I'm attempting to and getting  a NullPointerException.  The templates directory is in my war directory.

`STGroup group = new STGroupDir("templates/default",'$','$');`
`ST stPage = group.getInstanceOf("page");`

Comment: At the time I implemented the advice I had was that v4 was not GAE-compatible, so I am using stringtemplate-3.0.jar instead. Annoying? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your "war/WEB-INF/lib" will certainly be on the `classpath`. Not sure how appropriate it is to have templates there, though.

Also take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808843/any-tutorials-on-setting-up-a-templating-framework-on-gae-java).

Comment: Thanks, but putting it in "war/WEB-INF/lib" does not work. I note on the SO question you link to that the first answer exposes the templates to HTTP (ugly, and I don't see why it would work) and the second suggests loading the template file into a String yourself and then passing to StringTemplate. For now I'm going to go with the latter approach, but I don't consider the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the root directory of your war/WEB-INF/classes directory and they will wind up in your classpath. If you're using maven to build you can put them in src/main/resources and they will be copied to your classpath at the root.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no such directory evident in Eclipse, but I am not permitted to make a new directory because (Eclipse says) it exists already. I suspect it is reserved for build outputs that are not created by my particular application. I tried creating a new directory called "class" and adding to the build path but that didn't work either.

Comment: No, that won't work. Just put them in the root of your java source directory and they should get copied to the correct location. So if you have something like src/com/foo/bar put them in src.